# Need some suggestions about how to reference outside control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I insert a Tabcontrol into a BorderControl. The Tabcontrol used seperate styles. Right now the Close Button inside Tabcontrol can refer to itself. So when click it the TabControl is closed ***I guess so***. Is it possible to refer the button to the Border control outside so that when close the Border control is collpased?

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160" MinWidth="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Margin="5,5,0,5" BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="1">
            <TabControl Margin="0,15,0,0" Style="{StaticResource StandardTabControl}" >
                <TabItem Header="Start">
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Border>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" Width="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></GridSplitter>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,5,5,5"></Border>
    </Grid>

</DockPanel>
```

[image]

After click the close button

[image: After click the close button]

And part of the styles of TabControl.

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Height="15" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
     <Ac:CloseTabItemAction TabItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" 
                            TabControl="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}}">                                               
     </Ac:CloseTabItemAction>
</i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<!--A lot more about styles-->
</Button>
```

Comment: What means "the control is closed"? I obviously know in terms of UI and user experience, but what do you do to achieve this? Showing the template for the tab item will for sure help.

Comment: @Alejandro i just want to collapse the BorderControl outside.

Comment: @Alejandro Actually i think i need to let the grid outside the blue BorderControl to Collapse After click the close button, which is complicated as the grid has minimum width..

Comment: @Alejandro Maybe I need to redesign the tabControl. Could you give an example to custom a TabControl with a rectangle surrounding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution using control template triggers in pure xaml

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Control>
        <Control.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"
                                          MinWidth="100"
                                          x:Name="column" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Margin="5,5,0,5"
                            BorderBrush="Aqua"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <TabControl Margin="0,15,0,0"
                                    Style="{StaticResource StandardTabControl}"
                                    x:Name="tabControl">
                            <TabItem Header="Start">
                            </TabItem>
                        </TabControl>
                    </Border>
                    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                                  Background="Transparent"
                                  Width="6"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"></GridSplitter>
                    <Border Grid.Column="2"
                            BorderBrush="Aqua"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Margin="0,5,5,5"></Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems,ElementName=tabControl}"
                                 Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="column"
                                Property="MinWidth"
                                Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="column"
                                Property="Width"
                                Value="0" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Control.Template>
    </Control>
</DockPanel>
```

based on the assumption that when `CloseTabItemAction` will be called it will remove the `TabItem` from the `TabControl`, the trigger will detect the same based on `HasItems` property and will collapse the column if there are no items

---

**EDIT**

based on the comments here are the finding. while resizing `GridSplitter` sets a `Local value` to the `ColumnDefinition`'s `Width` property which have higher [`precedence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx#listing) than the `Trigger` values so the Trigger effectively fails to modify the value.

the solution proposed is to use `Animation` to set the desired value as Animations has higher precedence then the Local value, and the desired value is applied to the property.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems,ElementName=T1}"
                    Value="false">
        <Setter TargetName="Co0"
                Property="MinWidth"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter TargetName="G1"
                Property="Width"
                Value="0" />
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Co0"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <GridLength>0</GridLength>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

in the above code I also make the splitter width to 0 so that there is no empty space on the left

Comment: @xun-bao wondering if this approach helped you or you still need some adjustments.

Comment: It works if u just ckick close. Yet after i drag the GridSpliter to change the width, closing the tab will not give the auto shrinking effect.Could u plz have a look ?https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cwak4fpucqy8p5h/AABTD7bDDhbiCDQyHOYQOMSza

Comment: also i tried to leave a grid in each column so that i could use `grid1.Visibility= Visibility.Collapsed` ,then the gridSpliter did not work as it's in a separate grid.

Comment: the reason is GridSpliter sets the local value for the column width and style trigger have lower precedence so it can not override it. lets see how we can solve the issue.

Comment: Great! keep asking, happy coding :)